# Save Windows 8 Files and Install Ubuntu

Tags: installation, files, migration

I would like to install Ubuntu on my laptop. I am new to Ubuntu and therefore have some questions:

1.My hardware is Acer Emachines Intel Celeron T3000 1.8 3 Gig of Ram and Native Intel Intergrated graphics card. Can I run Ubuntu on this machine without any problems?

2.I am windows user and currently have windows 8. I want to install ubuntu but want to save all my directories on C:\ D:\ disks so that I can open my files in ubuntu. Is it possible to save my current directory system and save all my files after installing ubuntu? Can I open all my files? I have very important data in files so I dont want to lose them at all :)

Thank You

Comment: make backups in an external media before you try anything new. Then copy your very important data in another external media. Then make a third copy. Make sure the backups and the copies are readable and not corrupted. People make mistakes. Power goes off. Bad things happen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure everything will work for you, BUT to be more sure I would just TRY ubuntu from the usb stick and see if graphics, sound, wifi are working properly without actually installing it and see if you can figure it out.

When installing you have the option to install it next to your current windows install and you should be able to access those files.

Here most of your questions will be answered.
http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Quantal

For me one of the things that I needed to learn making the switch was that
ubuntu/unix/linux does not have a C:\ en D:\ drives these are just 'windows names' for chunks of memory mapped directly on hard drives or partitions.

You're in for an interesting ride!

Answer (score 0):

1. To answer the first item, if you want a detailed list that you can check one by one, choose the version of Ubuntu you're planning on installing here: [Official Ubuntu Documentation Site](https://help.ubuntu.com/) and most of them (other than 12.10 I think) have a section which gives you installation information and they cite system requirements as an example I've taken the 12.04 documentation below so you have an idea of how to navigate to the right section: [image]
2. Copying everything on your directory is easily done if you have an external hard-drive large enough (*though it may be slow depending on the amount you have to copy*), I'm not familiar with software which does it automatically but from my experience I've found copying and pasting the contents onto a hard-drive into folders named `C` and `D` was usually enough for me.

As a side-note if you'd like a quick introduction/comparison for people used to Windows, I'd suggest having a look at the following [Community Page on Switching to Ubuntu from Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows#Safely_Removing_Drives). I knew very little about Ubuntu myself when I decided to switch and it helped me with the basics. Hope you enjoy Ubuntu as much as I have!